# Exception Stacking Entry when using function

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am using an STM32F407 with MikroC compiler. I have some code that when I use in a function causes an Exception Stacking Entry but the same lines of code used normally works fine.

```
char *gridVoltage ;
float convertedVolt;

char gridVoltStr[4][10]= {{'0','0','0','0','0','0'},{'0','0','0','0','0','0'},
{'0','0','0','0','0','0'},
{'0','0','0','0','0','0'}};

void getInverterData(){

        gridVoltage = readMeasurementParamaters(2);
        convertedVolt = rebuildFloatVal(gridVoltage);
        FloatToStr(convertedVolt, gridVoltStr[0]);

}

void main() {


      GPIO_Digital_Output(&GPIOD_BASE, _GPIO_PINMASK_ALL);
      GPIOD_ODR = 0;

      // Configure GPIOC_BASE.2 pins as digital output :
         GPIO_Config(&GPIOC_BASE,  _GPIO_PINMASK_2 ,  _GPIO_CFG_MODE_OUTPUT | _GPIO_CFG_SPEED_MAX | _GPIO_CFG_OTYPE_PP);


      UART1_Init(19200);
      Delay_ms(100);
      UART2_Init_Advanced(19200, _UART_8_BIT_DATA, _UART_NOPARITY, _UART_ONE_STOPBIT, &_GPIO_MODULE_USART2_PD56);
      Delay_ms(100);


      //getInverterData();


      gridVoltage = readMeasurementParamaters(2);
      convertedVolt = rebuildFloatVal(gridVoltage);
      FloatToStr(convertedVolt, gridVoltStr[0]);


      while(1) {
           //  Do stuff
      }

}
```

The readMeasurementParamaters function justs send uart data and recieves it and returns a pointer to that data. When the function name is commented out like shown it works fine but including the function does not. This code will get called multiple times so I cannot keep re-writing the code. I have never seen this issue before and am unsure how to solve it. Any ideas??

Thanks.

Edit 1:

So I managed to get it working. The readMeasurementParamaters() function which is:

```
char* readMeasurementParamaters(char devAddr){

 float gridVoltage;
 char gridVoltagetxt[15];
 char *rxData;
 int crcOK, crcRx, crcCheck, i;
 char readMeasurementParamsCmd[8] = {0,59,1,32,0,0,0,0};
 readMeasurementParamsCmd[0] = devAddr;

 rxData = requestInverterData(readMeasurementParamsCmd) ;

 crcRx = Crc16(rxData, 0, 6);
 crcCheck = rxData[6]  << 8 | rxData[7] ;

 if(crcRx == crcCheck){
    gridVoltage = rebuildFloatVal(rxData);
    FloatToStr(gridVoltage, gridVoltagetxt);

    UART1_Write_Text("Voltage is:  ");
    for ( i = 0; i < 15; i++ ) {

         UART1_Write(gridVoltagetxt[i]);
         UART1_Write_Text("   ");
    }
    UART1_Write_Text(newline);
    UART1_Write_Text(newline);
 }
 else
    UART1_Write_Text("CRC Error :  ");

 return rxData;
```

}

I took this code and put it inside the  getInverterData() function and renamed some variables to get the following:

```
void getInverterData(char devAddr){


float gridVoltage;
char gridVoltagetxt[15];
char *rxData;
int crcOK, crcRx, crcCheck, i;
char readMeasurementParamsCmd[8] = {0,59,1,32,0,0,0,0};
readMeasurementParamsCmd[0] = devAddr;

rxData = requestInverterData(readMeasurementParamsCmd) ;

crcRx = Crc16(rxData, 0, 6);
crcCheck = rxData[6]  << 8 | rxData[7] ;

if(crcRx == crcCheck){
    gridVoltage = rebuildFloatVal(rxData);
    FloatToStr(gridVoltage, gridVoltStr[0]);

    UART1_Write_Text("Voltage is:  ");
    for ( i = 0; i < 15; i++ ) {

         UART1_Write(gridVoltagetxt[i]);
         UART1_Write_Text("   ");
    }
    UART1_Write_Text(newline);
    UART1_Write_Text(newline);
}
else
    UART1_Write_Text("CRC Error :  ");  


}
buildInvDataJsonString();
```

}

Its probably down to the nested functions. Still not entirely sure why it didn't work in the first place.

Comment: Proper formatting would improve readability tremendously...

Comment: You do not call `delay_ms` and `buildInvDataJsonString` in the commented variant. What makes you sure the error is not there?

Comment: Offtopic: Make variables local to where they really are needed, the `float` and `char*` do not need to be global (although you'd need to repeat them in main then). Global variables can lead you into deep trouble if not used correctly, not having them right from the start makes your code safer. And you can have initialisation easier: `char gridVoltStr[4][10] = { { '0' } };`; if first element is initialised, others are zero-initialised. Actually, you profit already from, you don't initialise all 10 values either...

Comment: @Aconcagua - delay_ms and buildInvDataJsonString are not there, this was a typo, they do not cause the issue. The first line is the problem as i have tried with the others commented out. I agree about local and global variables but this does not solve my issue.

Comment: That's why I classified `off-topic`... Fault looks strange, though. Have you debugged?

Comment: Yes, when I step through and I literally get to the last closing curly bracket of that function and an Exception Stacking Entry message pops up. Source is a hardfault and shows : xPSR - 0x6000000, PC- 0x00004D4C, LR- 0x00004D4C, R12- 0x00010C36, R3- 0x00000001, R2- 0x20000048, R1- 0x00000000, R0- 0x00000000

Comment: Hm, will get back here later. Currently too busy to investigate that deep...

Comment: So I took the readMeasurementParamaters() function and put that inside the getInverterData() function and it works. See the edits above.

Comment: Everything about this problem sounds like a stack overflow or other memory corruption. `rxData = requestInverterData(readMeasurementParamsCmd) ;` looks fishy, where is the memory actually allocated?

Comment: @Lundin - there is a pointer  RxData on the third line of the function. The actual recieved data is is in an array written to in another function. RxData is just pointing to this data.

Comment: Yes I realize that much but where is the memory allocated and how?

Comment: it is HardFault - most probably you write or read illegal memory

Comment: Difference between your actual implementation (char* readMeasurementParamaters(char devAddr)) and workaround (void getInverterData(char devAddr))is return value. Implies in readMeasurementParamaters function rxData is pointing to some wrong address. Have a look at your requestInverterData function.

Comment: Yes it looks like rxData was pointing to the wrong place. This name was used locally in a few different functions so probably got mixed up somewhere. Still the original getInverterData(); function which did not pass or return anything as rxData stayed where it was whether using the function call or direct code instead.